# Subsets of plane similar to any of their affine images

Tags: geometry, affine-geometry

I wonder which subsets of plane $X$ have a property that under any affine transformation $T$ there exists a similarity $S$ such that $S(T(X))=X$ so it essentially returns $X$ to its original form. 
Couple observations: 
1) If $X$ has this property then $X'$ also has it ($X'$ is a complement of $X$) 
2) Any set that is a subset of some line has this property. 
3) Parabola has it too 
I have also some conjectures:
1) Every such set which is not a subset of any line has to be infinite. 
2) Every such set which is not a subset of any line has to be unbounded. 
My question is are these conjectures true? Is there any nice characterization of such sets? Or there are some "pathological" examples?